# Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context i know its alreaduy disccused but didn't unders

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.4

Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context I don't know how to fix this problem

```
private  fun uploadImageToFirebaswStorage(){
    if (selectedphotoUri = null) return
    val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
     val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

    ref.putFile(selectedphotoUri!!)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("Register","Successfully uploaded image: ${it.metadata?.path}")}
```

Answer (score 1):

`selectedphotoUri = null` is an assignment. Most likely, you want `selectedphotoUri == null` (two equals signs), which is the equality expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to do an equality check as CommonsWare points out, another option would be to use a common [Kotlin idiom involving](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#execute-if-not-null) [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)

> val value = ...
>
> value?.let {
>       ... // execute this block if not null }

```
private  fun uploadImageToFirebaswStorage(){
    selectedphotoUri?.let {
        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")    
        ref.putFile(selectedphotoUri!!)
          .addOnSuccessListener {
              Log.d("Register","Successfully uploaded image: ${it.metadata?.path}")
          }
     }
}
```